# pytest-timeit or pytest-benchmark which one is better in terms of accuracy s?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, benchmarking, pytest, timeit

I am testing response status code and data of flask-restful api in pytest , now I would like to test the time these end points are taking , I am considering pytest-timeit a benchmark plugin , does anyone know what is more accurate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pytest-benchmark` is the clear choice.

You can run the `benchmark` function times and provide a more detailed summary of its running time.

You can do that obviously manually in `timeit`. But not worth the time given the feature rich and well documented `benchmark` function.

Read More on benchmark [here](http://pytest-benchmark.readthedocs.io/en/latest).